# Multicasting C++ multiple computers on the same LAN

Tags: java, c++, sockets, udp, multicast

i am working on an assignment for college, i was asked to implement a chat for the LAN of my college.
I am in the process of working with multicast for sending a same message to all registered users on the group. My sender is developed on C++ and the receivers on java. When testing on the same computer the code that i am attaching works fine, sender sends, and receiver receives, but when running client on another computer it does not receive the messages sent.

Server:

```
int main(){

/** MC socket **/

struct sockaddr_in groupSock;
groupSock.sin_family = AF_INET;
groupSock.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("225.5.4.30");
groupSock.sin_port = htons(54321);
    bzero(&(groupSock.sin_zero),8);

int mcsock;
if ((mcsock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) == -1) {
        perror("Socket MC");
        exit(1);
    }

int nroM = 0;
while(1)
{
    fflush(stdout);

    stringstream resp; 
    resp << "Mensaje multicast: " << nroM << "\n";
    cout << resp.str();
    /* Send a message to the multicast group specified by the*/
    /* groupSock sockaddr structure. */
    /*int datalen = 1024;*/
    if(sendto(mcsock, resp.str().c_str(), strlen(resp.str().c_str()), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&groupSock, sizeof(groupSock)) < 0)
    perror("Sending datagram message error");
    nroM++;
    sleep(2);
}

close(mcsock);
    return 0;

}
```

Client:

```
class UDPCliente {
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{

InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("225.5.4.30");
// Create a buffer of bytes, which will be used to store
// the incoming bytes containing the information from the server.
// Since the message is small here, 256 bytes should be enough.
byte[] buf = new byte[256];
// Create a new Multicast socket (that will allow other sockets/programs
// to join it as well.
try (MulticastSocket clientSocket = new MulticastSocket(54321)){
    //Joint the Multicast group.
    clientSocket.joinGroup(address);
    while (true) {
    // Receive the information and print it.
    DatagramPacket msgPacket = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
    clientSocket.receive(msgPacket);
    String msg = new String(buf, 0, buf.length);
    System.out.print(msg);
    }
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Just for extra information, this code with the appropiate imports and includes compile and run.

Thank you!!

Comment: Have you ensured that the two machines' firewalls will allow your chat traffic through?

Comment: Ill manage to see if possible, but i believe i dont have those permissions anyway to change firewalls settings, i believe teachers considered that.

Comment: ps: i managed to comunicate different computers with unicast. if thats useful to check if its really the firewall the problem. thx for the quick response.

Comment: Firewalls typically operate on a per-protocol and per-port basis.  If you're unsure whether a firewall is getting in the way, then the quickest way to test that is to turn off both machines' firewalls and try again.  Be certain to turn both firewalls back on immediately afterward.

Comment: There is also the possibility of traffic filtering at the router.  If that's happening then you can probably work around it for testing purposes by connecting both machines to the same (dumb) network hub or switch, so that they can communicate with each other without going through the router.

Comment: i dont have privileges to manage the firewalls. I did a ping and traceroute to another computer ip and both commands respond. So i guess udp packets are not blocked.

Comment: `ping` and `traceroute` do not address the question, as they will be directed to different ports than the one to which your client is listening.  I might have suggested testing via `telnet`, but not for UDP.  If the problem indeed is with the firewall(s), then you will need the assistance of someone who does have privileges.  Alternatively, you could find or set up a test machine on which you do have privileges.

Comment: alright, ill try to test the code somewhere else. Just to make sure, i managed to send messages from one computer to another using unicast, opening an udp socket, and sending it to another udp socket in the other computer, im learning about this, i dont know if the packets that are treated differently if they are unicast or multicast.

Comment: Firewalls can be very specific about what they allow through and what they don't.  This channel is not suited to troubleshooting the details for you.  I cannot say for sure that your firewall is the problem, but that's always one of the first things to check, and none of the tests you describe performing clearly rule it out.  Again, the easiest way to rule it out is to take all firewalls out of the picture and see whether the problem remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, apparently i changed to another computer and the code worked. So the firewall had something to do. Im answering so if anybody needs the same problem, the code i attached works perfectly if including and importing the proper libraries!!